# Why did Noah say, "tic-tac-toe"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-ultimatum

Before they bring an asset up from Casablanca, Noah's team are following
movements of Neal Daniels, a CIA station chief involved with Treadstone
and Blackbriar:

> Noah: Give me the subject's location.
>
> Man: Subject is now on foot and entering Hotel Velasquez. Hotel is 2.2
> kilometers from the bank.
>
> Noah: All right, get an elevation and a floor plan, **tic-tac-toe**.

Why did Noah say, "tic-tac-toe" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely because they are going to view the hotel as a 3D tic-tac-toe game. The elevation and floor plan gives them the game board - all the possible “squares” or rooms in the hotel where Daniels might go or hide. Then they just have to put their people in the right places to surround him, trap him, and/ or cut him off from escape. Like a complicated game of tic-tac-toe.